# How to add two GADBanners Ads on one viewcontroller for iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, adbannerview

I need to add two GADBannerView on one screen. How to identify which banner is for top and bottom. Is there any specific slots. I am very new to google mobile ads.

Comment: Create tow GADBannerView in your .h file and set that both bannerview frame diffrently .

Comment: @Darshan Kunjadiya - Thanks for your reply. I need two different banners with same adUnitID value. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it's possible just create GADBannerView twice and set that position diffrent

Comment: Is GADBannerView expecting any Top and bottom slots from client side? So that i have to get the parameters from Api calls. I should pass to GADBannerView. For ex: I will get the parameters like width,height, Ad slot(top or bottom) and one tag value etc.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to create to variables to handle the two banners.
Then display them into differents frames to gets them displayed at same time.

In the delegate methods, test the GADBannerView variable against your two created variable to know which one it is.